# Wordpress - can't edit pages anymore

Tags: wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I took over support for a wordpress site that has been around for a while but lightly used.  I had no idea what the admin did but I can't edit pages anymore.  The pages themselves so fine on the site - it is only when they are in edit mode that they are unreadable.  I did some research and I see that there are different editors that can be used.  If I try to click on either of the buttons above the text ("Content Composer", "Block editor") nothing happens.

Anyway, any help in this area would be GREATLY appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its almost always the plugins that cause this.  The funny thing is that I never figured out which one.  I disabled them all and then added them back in one at a time.  Everything was fine after that.